# Computation of group homology $H_2 ((\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}) \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

In my research I need to compute the group homology of the dicyclic group Dic3, which is a semi-direct product of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and let's denote it by $G$, we have a short exact sequence,
\begin{equation}
0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
My idea is to use Lyndon–Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence
\begin{equation}
H_p(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}, H_q(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})) \Rightarrow H_{p+q}(G,\mathbb{Z})
\end{equation}
We already know that 
\begin{equation}
H_2(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})=H_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})=0
\end{equation}
so we deduce that 
\begin{equation}
H_2(G,\mathbb{Z})=H_1(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}, H_1(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})) 
\end{equation}
We also know 
\begin{equation}
H_1(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}
**Question 1**: Does $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ acts trivially on $H_1(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$?

If so, we could conclude that $H_2(G,\mathbb{Z})=0$.

**Question 2**: If the action of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ on $H_1(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$ is not trivial, do we still have
$$H_1(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}, H_1(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})) =0 $$

Comment: $H_1(-,\mathbf{Z})$ is the abelianization, so here the action identifies to the original one. So Question 1 has a negative answer.

Comment: @YCor, Thank you. What about Question 2? There is only one non-trivial action of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Are there any references which might be helpful?

Comment: But $G$ has cyclic Sylow subgroups, from which we can conclude that $H_2(G,{\mathbb Z})=0$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I feel sorry for my naiveness, could you give me a reference for this fact?

Comment: You could start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_multiplier or https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Schur_multiplier

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you very much. This is very helpful.

Comment: To directly address Question 2, I'm pretty sure that if $F$ is a finite group and $V$ a finite $F$-module with $|F|$, $|V|$ coprime, then $H_1(F,V)=0$ although I don't have a reference.

Comment: Yes that's right. In fact $H_i(F,V)$ and $H^i(F,V)$ are zero for all nonzero $i$. This is in VI.8 of K.S. Brown's book on Cohomology of Groups, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the spectral sequence, notice that by the remarks of YCor and Derek Holt, it is almost trivial: since the orders of $Z/4$ and $Z/3$ are prime to each other, all homology groups of the form $H_p(Z/4,H_q(Z/3,Z))$ are zero when $p\neq 0$ or $q\neq 0$. The only remaining groups are on the ``bounadry'' of the spectral sequence, and all differentials are trivial. It thus holds that $H_n(G,Z) = H_n(Z/3,Z)^{Z/4}\oplus H_n(Z/4)$. To understand the action of $Z/4$, you can simply check it on the level of resolutions. Write the standard resolution for $Z$ over $Z/3$. You will then find out that $H^n(Z/3,Z)$ is zero for $n$ even, and is $Z/3$ for $n$ odd. The action of a generator of $Z/4$ is then by $-1$ if $n=4k+1$  and is trivial if $n=4k+3$. 
In particular, $H_2$ is trivial (but this way you can also calculate all the homology groups).